# Is there a way to make a completely transparent UIButton that works?

Tags: swift, uiview, touch, action, opacity

I've a custom UINavigationItem title view. It has a label pushed to the top of it, which I've enabled to respond to .touchDown and send an action.

However, the taps don't register near the top of the label, presumably because the active region is clipped.  So I configured another invisible view (not in navigation item), and set it up as a control, and positioned it above that navigation title view label.

However,  it doesn't work unless I set the 'invisible' view's alpha to at least 0.02, because Apple seems to intentionally disable action for a view with an alpha less than that. Unfortunately, against a black screen in dark mode, the 'invisible' hitpad view shows up as a slightly grey rectangle, which is not a good aesthetic.

I guess I could go to some lengths to try to make the button background color match the screen background at that location, but it seems a bit tacky.

What alternatives might I have?

Comment: Have you tried a transparent image? Or just a view with clear background and a UITapGestureRecognizer?

Comment: @LeoDabus: UIColor.clear background, yes,  and it didn't work, but didn't try w/the tap recognizer. I guess I can experiment some more. TY.

Comment: Make sure to set your view `userInteractionEnabled` to `true`. Again just a regular view. No need to use a button

Comment: Just tried a clear view with a tap gesture recogniser, as thinking along the same lines, and no joy.  Change it to a color and the gesture recogniser works :(

Comment: Why don’t you use a tap gesture recognizer? You can always use the tap location to decide if it is inside a region of your interest. No need to worry about the transparency of a view!

Comment: btw, tap gestures are recognizable when the backgroundColor is set to clear. I am currently using that in a project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a blank png image, and add it in top of your title view. make sure to set the imageView and the title view `isUserInteractionEnabled` properties to `true`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(
            target: self,
            action: #selector(tap)
        )
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        imageView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "blank")
        let titleLabel = UILabel()
        titleLabel.text = "Transparent Button"
        titleLabel.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        titleLabel.addSubview(imageView)
        navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
        navigationItem.titleView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    @objc func tap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print(#function)
    }
}
```

---

[Sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7i4c8efwh7jlc8z/Transparent%20View.zip?dl=0)

---

You can also just add your gesture recognizer directly to your titleView. No need for the transparent image at all unless you need to control the area of the gesture:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(
            target: self,
            action: #selector(tap)
        )
        let titleLabel = UILabel()
        titleLabel.text = "Transparent Button"
        titleLabel.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        titleLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
        navigationItem.titleView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    @objc func tap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print(#function)
    }
}
```

Comment: No doubt at all that will work, will check it out soon and get back. Tnx again.

Comment: @clearlight You can also just add your gesture recognizer directly to your `titleView`. `titleLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)` No need for the transparent image at all unless you need to control the area of the gesture.

Comment: @clearlight What is really important here is to set `navigationItem.titleView?.isUserInteractionEnabled` to `true`

Comment: @clearlight So what you trying is to tap the navigation bar not the title view.

Comment: Just add the tap gesture reconizer to it as well `navigationController?.navigationBar.addGestureRecognizer(tap)`

Comment: I posted an answer based on yours, accepted your answer, and cleared out my comments and noise. TY

Answer (score 1):

This is an adaptation of the @LeoDabus' Accepted answer that works. However it was utterly informed by his explanation and example. The only meaningful change I made to Leo's example was to create a *real* empty image programmatically, and drop the label generation.  Without a real empty UIImage(),  the only way to make taps on the region work that I found is to set the image view's background color to non-clear.

```
func emptyImage(with size: CGSize) -> UIImage?
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}

func configureButtons() {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: emptyImage(with: CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width - 250, height: 44)))
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 140, y: self.view.safeAreaInsets.top + 50,
                             width: view.frame.size.width - 250, height: 44)
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(actionEnableTitleEditing))
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    imageView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    view.addSubview(imageView)
}
```